# Generate multiple json files from text file

Tags: php, json

I am in need of help on how to generate multiple JSON files from data from a text file. I have a JSON file "file1.json" with following structure:

```
{
    "level": [
        6, 6, 4, 4, 2, 2, 3, 3, 6, 6,
        0, 2, 3, 3, 6, 6, 4, 4, 3, 3,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    ]
}
```

I have a text file with similar data but not in json format and separated by a line:

```
8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8,
0, 6, 6, 4, 4, 2, 2, 3,
2, 2, 3, 3, 6, 6, 4, 4,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,

6, 6, 4, 4, 2, 2, 3, 3,
0, 6, 6, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4,
0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0,

0, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 0,
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
```

I am looking for a solution to help extract the data and create a json file in the above format with file name incremental like file2.json, file3.json etc but have not been able to find a solution to this as I have over 600 of these file to create.

Based on online search, it appears PHP might do but I have no knowledge of PHP. Any help or pointing me to a possible solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested with the foreach loop, but by setting the `$content` static.

```
<?
$path = "/path/to/files/";
$files = array_diff(scandir($path), array('..', '.'));

foreach($file in $files)
{
    $content = file_get_contents($path . $file, true);
    /*
    $content = "8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8,
    0, 6, 6, 4, 4, 2, 2, 3,
    2, 2, 3, 3, 6, 6, 4, 4,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,";
    */
    $content = preg_replace('/[^\d,]/i', '', $content);
    $_content = array_filter(explode(',', $content));
    echo json_encode(array('level' => array_values($_content)));
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Do I need to run this on a linux machine?

Comment: No, you can use windows path. just remember to escape your slashes. (dubble slash)

Comment: hi, "/path/to/files/" , what path is that?